# verifying text before and after clicking link using something like contain

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have some links on my page where I'm trying to validate the text before and after click.

If the link text before click is "one two" and after click it is "one two", then test case pass. But if the text is "two one" after click, it is fail.

I have used `expect(before click).tocontain(afterclick)` and `expect(before click).matches(afterclick)`. Both doesn't work, so I'm looking for something like just contains.

Can you help me if there is something like that?

verifylinks() {

```
    var alllinks = element.all(by.css('div>h3>a'));

    browser.sleep(15000); // just for debug purpose to wait page loading.

    alllinks.count().then(function (length) {

        console.log('link amount: ' + length);

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {


            alllinks.get(i).getText().then(function (linktextbeforeclick) {

                var string = linktextbeforeclick.replace(/\(|,/g, '');
                var textbeforeclick = string.replace(/\)|,/g, '');

                console.log("textbeforeclick:" + textbeforeclick);
                alllinks.get(i).click();

                browser.sleep(5000);

                element(by.css('div>h2')).getText().then(function (linktextafterclick) {

                    var string = linktextafterclick.replace(/\(|,/g, '');
                    var textafterclick = string.replace(/\)|,/g, '');

                    console.log("textafterclick:" + textafterclick);

                    expect(textbeforeclick).toContain(textafterclick);
                })

                browser.navigate().back();
            })

        }



    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
verifylinks() {
  let alllinks = element.all(by.css('div>h3>a'));

  alllinks.count().then(function(count){
    console.log('link amount:', count);

    for(let i=0;i<count;i++) {

      let beforeText = getLinkText(alllinks.get(i));
      alllinks.get(i).click();
      browser.sleep(5000);

      let afterLink = element(by.css('div>h2'); 
      // confirm the locator for finding after click link is correct.

      let afterText = getLinkText(afterLink);

      Promise.all([beforeText, afterText])
             .then(function(txts){
               console.log('link text before click:', txt[0]);
               console.log('link text after  click:', txt[1]);
               expect(txt[0]).toEqual(txt[1]);
             });

      browser.navigate().back();
      browser.sleep(5000);
    }
  });
}

getLinkText(link) {
  return link.getText().then(function(str){
    return str.replace(/\(|,/g, '').replace(/\)|,/g, '').trim();
  });
}
```

Comment: @manaswini,  please share your code in plain text, rather than screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `async/await` (which I highly recommend, it takes a lot of the pain out of writing sequential tests in an asynchronous language), it would be something like

```
const link = element(...);

const beforeText = await link.getText();

await link.click()

const afterText = await link.getText();

expect(beforeText).toEqual(afterText);
```